# Postgresql v12 reference partitioned table to partitioned table but not with partition key

Tags: postgresql, reference, foreign-keys, partitioning, postgresql-12

I've been trying to reference partitioned table in postgresql v12 but got an issue.
The tables are partitioned by `range` on a date column, and the values for each partition are month delimiter (eg: FOR VALUES FROM ('2020-04-01T00:00:00') TO ('2020-05-01T00:00:00'))

I have 2 tables:

```
Table A
     Column      |           Type           | Collation | Nullable | Default 
-----------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 uuid            | character varying(36)    |           | not null | 
 start_date      | timestamp with time zone |           | not null | 
Partition key: RANGE (start_date)
Indexes:
    "table_a_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (uuid, start_date)

Table B
     Column      |           Type           | Collation | Nullable | Default 
-----------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 uuid            | character varying(36)    |           | not null | 
 start_date      | timestamp with time zone |           | not null | 
 ref_a_id        | character varying(36)    |           | not null | 
Partition key: RANGE (start_date)
Indexes:
    "table_b_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (uuid, start_date)
```

When adding a primary key to a partition table, I know that the partition key must be included. However, the `table_a.start_date` and `table_b.start_date` don't perfectly match, only the month of both dates should match in general and of course, the `ref_a_id` to `uuid`.

So far, this is what i tried:

```
ALTER TABLE table_a ADD CONSTRAINT ref_fk FOREIGN KEY (ref_a_id) REFERENCES table_b (uuid) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
-> ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "table_b"

ALTER TABLE table_a ADD CONSTRAINT ref_fk FOREIGN KEY (ref_a_id) REFERENCES table_b DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
-> ERROR:  number of referencing and referenced columns for foreign key disagree

ALTER TABLE table_a ADD CONSTRAINT ref_fk FOREIGN KEY (ref_a_id, start_date) REFERENCES table_b (uuid, start_date) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
```

The latter works, but at import time I got

```
-> ERROR:  insert or update on table "table_b" violates foreign key constraint "ref_fk"
DETAIL:  Key (ref_a_id, start_date)=(XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX, 2020-05-27 01:32:13+00) is not present in table "table_a".
```

The only solution I see right now, is to add a new column `year_month` with values like `2020_04` and do the partitioning by `list` on this new column. Therefore the reference should match.

Is there another solution? Is there a way I could reference only the month of the `start_date` columns instead of adding a new column? Or even maybe reference only the `table_a.uuid`?

Answer (score 0):

You should split the column in two parts, a `year_month` of type `date` that contains the date, rounded to months, and an `offset` of type `interval` that stores the difference to `start_date`. Then you can use the first column in your constraint.

Comment: Is there a difference in performance between your suggestion and doing the partitioning by `list` on a `varchar` column ?

Comment: Never, never store dates in a string column. You are missing out on value checking, date arithmetic and waste storage space to boot. So yes, this can be performance relevant, but that's not the main issue.

Comment: So there would be no other solution than adding a new column (or splitting start_date)? No matter how this new column is formatted.

Comment: I cannot think of a better solution. That doesn't imply that no such solution exists.